# How do you pull a entry field in a global out in a template

Tags: templating, entry

I am trying to create an easy way to make a sticky post on my blog and I am using an entry field within a global.

Not sure where to even start to pull this out in a template.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can access and loop the entrie in any template like so:

```
{% for entry in globalSetHandle.entriesFieldHandle %}
    {{ entry.title }}
{% endfor %}
```

If you want to change the sort order to show the most recent blog post first use the relatedTo parameter:

```
{% for entry in craft.entries.relatedTo(globalSetHandle).order('dateUpdated desc') %}
    {{ entry.title }}
{% endfor %}
```